# How can I forecast a 2000 vehicles engine hours separately using R language?

Tags: python, r

machines: m1, m2, m3,... m2000
date:    2016, 2016, 2016...2016
engine hours: 200, 300, 30,....700.
Think each machine has some 200 rows of data in 2016, how can I forecast engine hours for 2017 for all 2000 machines.

Comment: Please provide an example dataset and focus your question better. As it stands now, your question is very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure if I got that right, the question is very unclear. 
You could use a [recurrent neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) ([LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network)) if your data is non-linear.

Available modules for Python are e.g. Keras or TensorFlow.

Also if your data is well-behaved you could also use an interpolation algorithm supporting extrapolation, like [radial basis functions (RBF, scipy.interpolate.Rbf)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html)